# Is there a way to create a mozila-like tab using css?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mozilla

I have been looking for a Latest  Firefox-like tab written using css but cannot find one.

Sorry, to make sure I am clear, I am trying to replicate the look in order to use it in a web application or a website

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

if you can have already a script (css) for tabs try to just play with the border radius:

```
border-radius: [first corner value]px [second corner value]px [third corner value]px [fourth corner value]px;
```

### PS (Hint)

The values in CSS can even be negative

Hope this [tries to] help